# No tables on heroku postgres even after backup restore successfull

Tags: php, postgresql, heroku, backup, pg-restore

I am new to this.

I have php server and postgres db on a local machine. After taking a backup of localdb via pgAdmin, i tried restoring it on heroku instance with the command

```
heroku pg:backups restore 'GOOGLE DRIVE LINK OF DUMP FILE' HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_RED
```

It says restore completed and backup successful on heroku pg:backups info r024

But on the heorku instance it shows me 0 tables and also the php project does not get connected to db.

Comment: what are first several lines of 'GOOGLE DRIVE LINK OF DUMP FILE'?..

Comment: what you see on "heroku pg:backups info r024  --app heroku-postgres-NNNNNNNN" ?..

Comment: status: Completed Successfully
Backup Size: 7.68 KB
//few log statements 
did not find magic string in header
restore done
download done

Comment: Thanks anyways. Found a work around. Made online scripts to create & manage a database on heroku.